# Contact thank you page

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

Currently My contact form goes to another page when submitted with an alert that says thankyou for contacting us but, what I want it to do is say thankyou for contact us as a pop up or text on the screen, anywhere to say thank you but just on the same page as the contact form

```
    <?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = ' dsaas@asadsd.asdasd';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');
        window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>



<form  action="contact.php" style="height:auto;"  class="form"  method="post">
    <h1>Your name</h1>
    <input type="text"  class="form textbox"  name="cf_name"><br>
    <h1>Your e-mail</h1>
    <input type="text" class="form textbox"  name="cf_email"><br>
    <h1>Message</h1>
    <textarea  class="form textbox"  name="cf_message"></textarea><br>
  <input  type="submit" value="Send">
```

I have tried replacing the if statement to

```
   if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <div><h1>thank you for submitting the contcat form</h1> </div>
    <?php
    }
```

But this still went to another page

Comment: This is to broad to answer here completely, but you need to look into ajax / javascript to subtmit your form and handle the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate your data before sending.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']){

    $field_name = isset($_POST['cf_name'])? $_POST['cf_name']:'';
    $field_email = isset($_POST['cf_email'])? $_POST['cf_email']:'';
    $field_message = isset($_POST['cf_message'])? $_POST['cf_message']:'';

    if(empty($field_name){
       $error = 'Field Name is blank';
    }elseif(empty($field_email) || filter_var($field_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
       $error = 'Email is invalid';
    }elseif(empty($field_message)){
       $error = 'Message is blank';
    }else{        
      $mail_to = ' dsaas@asadsd.asdasd';
      $subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;
      $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
      $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
      $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
      $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
      $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
     if($mail_status){ ?>
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        document.getElementById("myForm").reset();//reset the form
    </script>
  <?php }else{  ?>
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');
        //document.getElementById("myForm").reset();//Reset the form
    </script>
 <?php  }
  }
}
```

Since you don't want to go to another, you can post in the same page by specifying the action like below or you don't necessarily need to do.

```
<form  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" 
   style="height:auto;"  class="form" id="myForm"  method="post">
    <h1>Your name</h1>
    <input type="text"  class="form textbox"  name="cf_name"><br>
    <h1>Your e-mail</h1>
    <input type="text" class="form textbox"  name="cf_email"><br>
    <h1>Message</h1>
    <textarea  class="form textbox"  name="cf_message"></textarea><br>
  <input  type="submit" value="Send">
 <div class="error">
    <?php if(!empty($error)){ echo $error; } ?>
 </div>
```

Hope this may help.